# raspberry pi 4B and arduino

Tags: pi-4, arduino

I installed the Arduino IDE, connected the boards through USB and the raspbian recognized the Arduino board on the `/dev/tty/acm0` port. I opened the blink example, loaded to the Arduino and got this message.:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: by the way. The arduino script verified ok.

Comment: Ah let me see.  So you are running an Arduino script in the Arduino IDE installed in Rpi. Perhaps the Arduino driver for Rpi is not that updated.  Or perhaps your Arduino board is not working.  One simple method to troubleshoot is this: (1) Install the Arduino IDE in WinPC Win10, and try you luck there to confirm that your Arduino board works perfectly with Win 10 but not with buster (is it buster?)

Comment: "I installed the Arduino IDE" How? What version?

Comment: I doubt the Pi is relevant to this problem.  Have you worked through the Arduino connection problems checklist?